# str_replace in php

Tags: php, str-replace

i have a long string that can hold all these values at the same time:

```
hello<!>how are you? <!>I am fine<!> What is up? <!> Nothing!
```

I need to find all these posibilities:

```
' <!> '
' <!>'
'<!> '
'<!>'
```

And replace them with "\n"

Can that be achieved with str_replace in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only have those 4 possibilities, yes, then you can do that with `str_replace`.

```
$str = str_replace( array( ' <!> ', ' <!>', '<!> ', '<!>' ), "\n", $str );
```

> Yeah, but what if there is two spaces ? Or a tab ? Do you add a spacial case for each ?

You can either add special cases for each of those, or use regular expressions:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/\s*<!>\s*/', "\n", $str );
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can achieve this with 4 calls to `str_replace`. **Edit:** I was wrong. You can use arrays in [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$str = str_replace(' <!> ', "\n", $str);
$str = str_replace(' <!>',  "\n", $str);
$str = str_replace('<!> ',  "\n", $str);
$str = str_replace('<!>',   "\n", $str);
```

Also consider using [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), that allows to do it in one step.

```
$str = strtr($str, array(
    ' <!> ' => "\n",
    ' <!>'  => "\n",
    '<!> '  => "\n",
    '<!>'   => "\n"
));
```

Or you can use a [regular expression](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$str = preg_replace('/ ?<!> ?/', "\n", $str);
```

Comment: @codeholic: You don't need 4 calls to str_replace. And he wanted to replace for "\n"

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can do it with str_replace like this:

```
$needles = array(" <!> ","<!> "," <!>","<!>");
$result = str_replace($needles,"\n",$text);
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if there is two spaces ? Or a tab ? Do you add a spacial case for each ?

Comment: @e-satis: The requirements are clear. If the OP didn't mean what he asked about or missed some details, he should edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: `preg_replace('/\s*<!>\s*', PHP_EOL, $string);` should be better.

Sure, `str_replace('<!>', "\n", $string);` if your example is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with just `str_replace`. Either use a combination of `explode`, `strip` and `implode`, or user `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
//get lines in array
$lines = explode("<!>", $string);
//remove each lines' whitesapce
for(i=0; $i<sizeof($lines); $i++){
    trim($lines[$i]);
}
//put it into one string
$string = implode("\n", $lines)
```

It's a bit tedious, but this should work (also removes two spaces, and tabs). (didn't test the code, so there could be errors)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of neat:

```
$array = explode('<!>', $inputstring);
foreach($array as &$stringpart) {
  $stringpart = trim($stringpart);
}
$outputstring = implode("\r\n", $array);
```